# Extra conjuncts in active record WHERE clause: Where are they coming from?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm getting a very strange database error when a CodeIgniter application I'm working with attempts a particular UPDATE operation.

The Active Record call is:

```
$this->db->update('eval_events',
                  array('eval_event_totalscore'=>$result['average_score'],
                        'eval_event_average_totalscore=>$result['average_score']),
                  array('eval_event_id'=>$eval_event_id));
```

And the reported error is:

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

UPDATE `eval_events` SET `eval_event_totalscore` = '40.0000', `eval_event_average_totalscore`
= '40.0000' WHERE `id` = '581' AND `id` = '581' AND `id` = '581' AND `id` = '581' AND `id` = 
'581' AND `id` = '581' AND `id` = '581' AND `id` = '581' AND `id` = '581' AND `id` = '581' AND 
`id` = '581' AND `id` = '581' AND `id` = '581' AND `id` = '581' AND `id` = '581' AND `id` = '581'
AND `eval_event_id` = '565'
```

Huh? Where the heck are all those extra conjuncts involving `id` coming from?

Clearly I'm not passing them, and my reading of `CI_active_record.php` has given me no clues.

Three additional pieces of information that may be relevant:

1. This failure is only happening on my development machine, as far as I can tell. The query seems to be fine on the production machine.
2. If I comment out this call to `update()`, the *following* call to `update()` gets corrupted in exactly the same way.
3. The value '581' is significant in the overall context of the operation that these updates are part of, but it's a key in a different table (and anyway, it's bound to a column named **`pid`**, not `id`).

It *feels* like the Active Record code has cached that `id` = '581', and something is causing it to cough the contents of that cache out into my UPDATE statement at this point.

I'll admit that I don't understand what Active Record's `start_cache()`/`stop_cache()`/`flush_cache()` methods are really supposed to be good for -- but it shouldn't matter, because `grep -r` tells me that there's no call to `start_cache()` anywhere in the application's codebase.

Just for grins I tried putting a call to `$this->db->flush_cache()` immediately before the failing `update()` call, but it didn't change anything.

I have no idea where to look next to try to figure this out.

Any ideas? Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay: `echo`, `var_export()` and `debug_print_backtrace()` to the rescue.

It turns out that there's a function that's called a total of 16 times before the function that makes the failing `update()` call. And 16 just happens to be the number of extra `id` = '581' conjuncts in the bad UPDATE statement.

And in that earlier function is the following code (I didn't write *any* of this garbage, BTW):

```
$this->db->where('id',$pid);  // <=== WTF???
$sql = "SELECT id FROM project_score WHERE pid=$pid AND uid=$uid AND scoretype=1";
$result = $this->db->query($sql)->row_array();
```

What's wrong with this picture?

Well, apart from the dubious choice of using Active Record *at all*,* the Active Record `query()` method doesn't use anything that's been squirreled away by prior calls to `where()`.

Consequently, that queue of 16 bogus conditions is still hanging around, waiting to attach itself to the first unsuspecting `update()` (or `select()`, or whatever) call that comes along.

Why doesn't this also happen on the production system?

Well, on my development system, I temporarily commented out something *else* (that I didn't really care about) that was failing because of some missing config in my local PHP -- which I didn't feel like rebuilding right then.

Apparently whatever I commented out contained an Active Record call that the got the queue of 16 conditions foisted off on it -- but they happened to be benign for that particular call.

Sheesh!

*So whose idea was this "Active Record" travesty, anyway?

How is it a good idea to have functions like `where()` that queue things up on a *global* object? Wouldn't a better design have been to make each SQL statement a different object, so that mistakes made while constructing one couldn't corrupt another in an entirely different part of the application?